# Instagram In-App Browser breaks Flutter Web Page

Tags: flutter, instagram, flutter-web

We used Flutter Web to develop our website and we encounter one issue only in the browser integrated in the Instagram app. If a user opens a link to our website in Instagram, the In-App-Browser shows the page totally strange (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/5geUn.png for the broken version and see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eDwb.png for how it should look like). This only happens on iOS and only if you open the link for the first time.

We have tried changing the web renderer but this introduces other layout issues (also only Instagram). If the user is reloading the page it fixes the problem, but if we do it programmatically with html.window.location.reload() it does not change anything. Do you have any idea what the problem could be or what else we could try to fix this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `flutter clean` and then building the project again?

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I have the same problem

Comment: Yes, with a workaround. We do not open the page directly, but use a different link which only redirects to the target page. This somehow fixes the problem for us.

Comment: Yeah I've been trying to use that solution too with firebase hosting redirects, if you use firebase could you share how it works?

Comment: I have created Dynamic Links with Firebase which simply redirect to the original page. But I guess, it should work with any other method of redirecting as well.

Comment: And just to be clear, do you just redirect to the home page? Is that all that is needed? E.g the link in instagram bio would be instagramlink.myapp.com and redirect to myapp.com?

Comment: Not to the homepage, because we directly link to certain routes in the web app. But I guess you meant only to the first page that is loaded, then yes. So if you want to only add a link to your home page in your Instagram bio, then it is enough to create and add a dynamic link for that page.

Comment: I see, if you could direct me to a resource for making dynamic links work for flutter. I would very much appreciate it. Alternatively, do you know if firebase hosting redirects would work?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

```
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --release
```

Somehow it helped, but I needed to wait like an hour till firebase hosting updated the site